# Rails/Ruby: Any way to shorten the stack traces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I would like to limit the size of the stack traces I am seeing in Rails. I'm not really interested in debugging the Rails stack as much as my own application. Is there any built-in way to have Rails do this dynamically?

Comment: So, did john's answer worked fine?

Comment: I just started with Rails 2.3, so I'll have to check it now. Please report back if you find that it's cool, marcgg... Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Take a look at the [ActiveSupport::BacktraceCleaner](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BacktraceCleaner.html) class. Nice explanation [here](https://afreshcup.com/home/2008/11/29/rails-23-backtrace-silencing).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't marked this best answer because I haven't tried it yet, but I will shortly. Thanks again, John.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the code with your own exception catcher and just output how much you want.

[Using the array from the backtrace-Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Exception.html)

Only alternative I could think of. Recompiling Ruby and changing the values which control the stack depth in [eval.c](http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/eval_8c-source.html) (TRACE_HEAD and TRACE_TAIL)

Comment: +1 Actually writing error-catching code?! Yeah, that would be a good idea in any case... Thanks for the answer.