# Can I limit the stack trace of runtime errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When there's an error in my code, I get a huge stack trace of Rails components. I'm only concerned with the stack trace of my own code. I don't want to see the lengthy stack trace when I know for sure that the error is in my own code.

Is there any way to limit the trace to my local code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails/Ruby: Any way to shorten the stack traces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003313/rails-ruby-any-way-to-shorten-the-stack-traces)

Comment: How are you seeing it? On the web browser, or console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "Application Trace" instead of full verbose backtrace in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979363/how-to-get-application-trace-instead-of-full-verbose-backtrace-in-rails)